# KDE taskbar labels disappear

Tags: linux-mint, kde, panel

I'm using Linux Mint 13 KDE.  If I open more than 9 windows at once, all the labels on all my taskbar buttons disappear.  Each one is left with only the icon, centered in its  taskbar button.  I found an Ubuntu bug about it ( https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kde-workspace/+bug/951553 ), but it's 8 months old and has no comments, which makes it seem like no one has seen it.

What I want is for the taskbar buttons to just continue to get smaller and smaller the more windows I open, with the labels more and more aggressively truncated as the buttons get smaller.  The labels already *are* truncated when I open up to 9 windows, but when I open the 10th one it seems to switch to this totally different icon-only display.  I don't want that.  I just want it to keep showing less and less of the label, gradually.  How can I achieve this?